# Who makes the Wifi component on the Macbook Pros?

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, hardware

In Apple's Macbook line, who is actually making the Wifi components for them? Intel?

I ask because I've never had any trouble with wireless connections on my Macbook but all the adapters I buy for my PC seem to degrade quickly over time and I'd like to buy something along the lines of what Apple is putting in their machines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the SystemProfiler -> Network -> Airport

```
Card Type:  AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0x8D)
Firmware Version:   Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.10.131.42.4)
```

Vendor ID 0x14E4 is for Broadcom http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendor_details.php?id=767